# Spark can't find Python module

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run the following Python script locally, using spark-submit command:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from commons.Utils import Utils

def splitComma(line):
    splits = Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)
    return "{}, {}".format(splits[1], splits[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[2]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    airports = sc.textFile("in/airports.text")
    airportsInUSA = airports\
    .filter(lambda line : Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)[3] == "\"United States\"")

    airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(splitComma)
    airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text")
```

The command used (while inside the project directory):

```
spark-submit rdd/AirportsInUsaSolution.py
```

I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/gustavo/Documentos/TCC/python_spark_yt/python-spark-tutorial/rdd/AirportsInUsaSolution.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from commons.Utils import Utils ImportError: No module named commons.Utils

Even though there is a commons.Utils with a Utils class.

It seems that the only `imports` it accepts are the ones from Spark, because this error persists when I try to import any other class or file from my project.

Answer (score 3):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def splitComma(line):
    splits = Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)
    return "{}, {}".format(splits[1], splits[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[2]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    sc.addPyFile('.../pathto commons.zip')
    from commons import Utils

    airports = sc.textFile("in/airports.text")
    airportsInUSA = airports\
    .filter(lambda line : Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)[3] == "\"United States\"")

    airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(splitComma)
    airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text")
```

Yes, it only accepts the ones from the Spark. You can zip the required files (Utils, numpy) etc and specify the parameter `--py-files` in the spark-submit.

```
spark-submit  --py-files rdd/file.zip rdd/AirportsInUsaSolution.py
```

Answer (score 0):

for python to consider a directory as package you need to create **__init__.py** in that directory. The **__init__.py** file doesn't need to contain anything.

In this case once you create **__init__.py** in the commons directory you will be able to access that package.

Answer (score -1):

Create a python script named: `Utils.py` which will contain:

```
import re

class Utils():

    COMMA_DELIMITER = re.compile(''',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)''')
```

Put this `Utils.py` python script on a `commons` folder and put this folder in your working directory (type `pwd` to know it). You can then import the `Utils` class:

```
from commons.Utils import Utils
```

Hope it will help you.